# Getting Data from Internet in Java

Tags: java, html, jnlp, web

I thought of making the following application for my college project in java. I know core java. I want to know what should i read "specifically" for this project as there is less time:

It will have an interface to put your query. This string would go as a query to internet search engines and with the help of search engine find the data (**the first web page that we see** (that is data for my application for this time. :) )).
I do not want to display the data. I just want the HTML file or the source code of the generated web page. Is it sounding like Common Getaway Interface? I do not know about this.

But i think it for the same purpose. If it is this. please guide me to know how to implement this.
Whatever please specify

- **Problem 1 :** What should i read ? Any direct help at this point is not my intention. I want to implement it myself.
- **Problem 2 :** Is connecting to internet requires some jnlp knowledge too.

for eg. as on google we search something it shows us the links of the websites. I can see the source code of this generated web page. I just want this page for my application to work on.

**EDIT**:
I do not want to rely on google only or any particular web server. I want to decide that by my application.
Please also refer to my problem 2.

As i discovered that we have Terms of Conditions for websites should i try to make my crawler. Would then my application not breaking the rules . Well its important for me.

Comment: but majorities of WebPages has TOC, where is clearly presented as that may be used, about digital ... and another words about distributions, restriction and owners ... :-)

Comment: So, what do you suggest that i should do ? should i go for only google apis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ashish,
         Here what I would recommend.

1. Learn the basics of JSON from these links ([Introduction](http://www.javapassion.com/ajax/JSON.pdf) ,[lib download](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/))
2. Then look at the Google Web Search JSON API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html).
3. Learn how to GET the data from servers using HttpClient library [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).
4. Now what you have to do is, fire a get request for the search, read the JSON response, parse the response using the JSON lib from #1 and you have the search results.
5. Most of the search engines (Bing etc) offer Jason/REST apis so you can do the same for other search engines.

Note: Jason APIs are normally used from JavaScritps on the UI side but since its very easy and quick to learn, I suggested you that.  You can also explore (if time permits) the XML based APIs also.

Comment: Thanks for your links. They are really starting points for me. Your 2. link to google web search json api . Would it be attachable to desktop application ? I thnk http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ should do. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes. It should be. Its an API and it should not matter whether its called from a web UI or a desktop application.

Answer (score 4):

```java
URL url = new URL("http://fooooo.com");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
  {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
  }
```

Should be enough to get you started .

And yes , do check if you are not violating the usage terms of a website . Search Engines dont really like you trying to access them via a program .

Many , Including Google , has APIs specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: How would i send the Query that i want to search on the web to any search engine without using the specific apis.

Comment: You could , but you would be violating the TOS of the sites . Wouldnt be long till one of them takes action against you , the lightest of which would be blacklisting your ip .I'd really suggest you make a service that would integrate the results you get from the various search engine API's , which would be the proper way of doing what you want.

Comment: So HTMLUnit can run javascript on the web pages. so can i do "THROUGH PROGRAMMING" whatever i want to serch on an engine :=> PUT my search query on the box and simulate the javascript code of the button. and get the document. Would that we violating the TOC of the web server?

Comment: you'll violate the TOS of the search provider . In case of google , quoting from http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS , "You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)..."

Comment: also , here is the what you should be doing , again in case of google http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: is what you gave is same as: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ and acessing the html web page of any website(other than search engines because it is there service) should not be against TOC because it is what every search engine do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3053/discussion-between-ashish-negi-and-amal)

Answer (score 2):

you can do everything you want using [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It´s like a web browser but for java. Check some examples at their website.

Comment: He mentioned _"I do not want to display the data. I just want the HTML file or the source code"_

Comment: so? htmlunit is not only about displaying data. lol he also mentioned:  "This string would go as a query to internet search engines and with the help of search engine find the data (the first web page that we see " for this reason it could be helpful.

Comment: @Maciejk So HTMLUnit can run javascript on the web pages. so can i do "THROUGH PROGRAMMING" whatever i want to serch on an engine :=> PUT my search query on the box and simulate the javascript code of the button. and get the document. Would that we violating the TOC of the web server?

Comment: @MaciejK is what you gave is same as: [link] (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? and acessing the html web page of any website(other than search engines because it is there service) should not be against TOC because it is what every search engine do? can we chat?

Answer (score 1):

Read "[Working with URL's](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)" in the Java tutorial to get an idea what is behind the available libs like HTMLUnit, HttpClient, etc

Comment: So HTMLUnit can run javascript on the web pages. so can i do "THROUGH PROGRAMMING" whatever i want to serch on an engine :=> PUT my search query on the box and simulate the javascript code of the button. and get the document. Would that we violating the TOC of the web server?

Comment: i am not rendering the web page. This is all happening virtually?

Comment: I read Working with URLs and writing to Url. Now that requires knowing in what format server is asking about the information. How would i come to know that?

Comment: You can't a priori. That is what "protocols" are for. Both parties agree to speak the same language/protocol. In your case it will be HTTP and the data will be written in HTML. What means that data in HTML is then specified in the API doc of a "web service".

Answer (score 1):

> *I do not want to display the data. I just want the HTML file or the source code of the generated web page.*

You probably dont need the HTML either. Google provide its search results as a web service using this [API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html). Similarly for other search engine [GIYF](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=yahooe+search+as+web+service). You get the search results as XML, which is far more easier for you to parse. Plus the XML wont have any unwanted data like ads.